# Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault

Tags: c, falha-de-segmentação

Quando chamo essa função acontece esse erro "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault."

```
void cria_agenda(Agenda *agenda_prof, int Id_prof, char *nome, int ano){
    agenda_prof->quant_compromissos = 0;
    agenda_prof->Id_prof = Id_prof;
    strcpy(agenda_prof->nome_prof, nome);
    agenda_prof->ano = ano;
    
}
```

A chamada e essa:

```
Agenda *agenda_prof[P];

int tam_agenda = 0;
char *nome = "felipe";
int ano = 2020;

cria_agenda(agenda_prof[tam_agenda],tam_agenda, nome,ano);
```

Comment: Creio que deveria alocar memória para o ponteiro antes

Answer (score 0):

O problema está em você criar um vetor de ponteiros de Agenda, a forma correta de fazer seria:

```c
Agenda agenda_prof[P];
cria_agenda(&agenda_prof[tam_agenda],tam_agenda, nome,ano);
```

O vetor que você havia criado só tem ponteiros para agendas, nenhum deles é realmente uma agenda, então não faz sentido tentar acessar algum campo que deveria haver em agenda. Outro erro que provavelmente vai dar no seu programa é no trecho que você usa strcpy, eu imagino que você esteja declarando um campo de ponteiro de caractere na sua agenda chamada nome_prof, isso irá provavelmente irá gerar falha de segmentação também, pois não tem um espaço alocado para o ponteiro e você vai tentar escrever nele mesmo assim, lembre-se de utilizar os métodos `malloc()` e/ou `calloc()` para não ter esse problema.

Obs: Da próxima vez que postar perguntas aqui coloque o código completo para que não haja confusão ou teorização sobre outros trechos do código que interferem no seu problema.